# How to set a variable within a class, then access/refer to it? PHP

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

class foo
{
    public $a;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $a='value';
    }

}

$class = new foo();
echo $class->$a;

?>
```

I want to use the value $a in other parts of my script.

How do I retrieve a variable set in a php object and use it for other things outside of the object?

Comment: Tons of good advice/examples on the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the value inside a method, the syntax is:

```
$this->a = 'value';
```

To obtain the value of the property from an instance of the class, the syntax is:

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->a;
```

The [Properties manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) goes into more detail.

Comment: Another way `$string = "a";` then `$this->$string = "value";`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a *getter* ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/2612112)):

Inside your class.

```
private $a;

public function getA()
{
    return $this->a;
}
```

Outside your class.

```
$class = new foo();
echo $class->getA();
```

**Important: Inside your class you should refer to `$a` as `$this->a`.**

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this` variable to assign and reference instance variables and functions on the current object.

In your case replace `$a = 'value';` with `$this->a = 'value';`